# Wildfly + Java 10 does not recognize REST resources

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, wildfly

If the maven compiler plugin is configured to compile to java 10, wildfly does not recognize any resources (rest). However, if I set it to compile the sources to java 8, no such problem occurs.

The problem can be seen in the following REPO: https://github.com/JurajMlich/lucy . If you remove source and target elements from pom.xml and uncomment release element, the endpoint /rest/test does not work. No error shows up in logs, 404 code is returned.

What is wrong?

Comment: What version of WildFly?

Comment: It looks like you're targeting EE 8 so presumably you're using Wildfly 13.  Are you running with Java EE 8 enabled (i.e. on the command line something like `./standalone.sh -Dee8.preview.mode=true`)?

Comment: If you're not using WildFly 13 you may be hitting https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-9961.

Comment: That's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using Wildfly12, which according to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-9961 has this issue. It it resolved in Wildfly13.